# Run .ipynb on Databricks without the import ui

Tags: databricks

Is there a way to run (or convert) .ipynb files on a Databricks cluster without using the import ui of Databricks. Basically I want to be able to develop in Jupyter but also be able to run this file on Databricks where its pulled trough git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to import Jupyter notebooks into Databricks workspace as a Databricks notebook, and then execute it.  You can use:

- [Workspace Import REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import)
- `databricks workspace import` command of [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html).

P.S. Unfortunately you can't open it by committing into a Repo, it will be treated as JSON. So you need to import it to convert into a Databricks notebook